# bash check mysql connect

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script to do some operations against a database on my debian squeeze Server.

I have noticed that if I enter a wrong password for root, the prompt will be closed and I won't be asked to try again... that's not very convenient!

So I was trying to create a loop that attempts to connect to MYSQL and save the password for later if successful.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.
Instead, I receive this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
read -s -p "Enter MYSQL root password: " mysqlRootPassword

while [[ -n `mysql -u root -p$mysqlRootPassword` ]]; do
       read -p "Can't connect, please retry: " mysqlRootPassword
done
```

I am not very experienced in bash scripting, any help would be awesome!

Comment: You might have better luck on serverfault.com, even though this is considered a programming question..

Comment: don't exactly what it references (found it on the web), but it's working fine! I admit that this is confusing, I'll edit my question and replace that with 'mysql'. Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think you need the `[[ -n backtic ... ]];` test nested like that. Try:

```
read -s -p "Enter MYSQL root password: " mysqlRootPassword

while ! mysql -u root -p$mysqlRootPassword  -e ";" ; do
       read -s -p "Can't connect, please retry: " mysqlRootPassword
done
```

`while` evaluates any command group upto a closing `; do` and checks the return code of last command executed to determine if the loop should be executed. Because you are looking for a failure, you have to precede the test with a logical NOT (`!`) OR you can use the syntactic equivalent, i.e.

```
until mysql -u root -p$mysqlRootPassword  -e ";" ; do
       read -s -p "Can't connect, please retry: " mysqlRootPassword
done
```

which you can think of as 'until mysql works correctly, keep trying to get the right password'.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to a mysql installation, so this is untested.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks dude, that was it! However, this will connect to mysql and display its prompt. To avoid that, here's the while statement: while ! mysql -uroot -p$mysqlRootPassword -e ";" ; do

Comment: @Erwan, glad that helped. I've editted my answer to include your improvement. Did I get it right? Thanks and good luck.

Comment: Works great. I added the -s option to the read in while as well to avoid the password being echoed.